# How to intercept URL request in firefox Addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to intercept the URL request before it is sent. e.g. to check the requested URL is not blacklisted. I found several Addon examples that do this like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/blocksite/?src=search. But they are bsed on XUL and I am looking for SDK that simplify this functionality. Is there any SDK for such function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way of doing this using SDK.